# Unable to find an object in a vector of object pointers

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a vector of Node*(openList) and I was hoping to get an iterator to the the Node* when a targetNode is given. It should check the x & z position and if a match is found, i would know that this Node* already exists. This is what I have

```
auto iter = std::find_if(openList.begin(), openList.end(), [&targetNode](const Node* p)
                {
                  return (targetNode->GetXPos() == p->GetXPos() && targetNode->GetZPos() == p->GetZPos());
                });
if (iter != openList.end())
{
  ....do something
}
```

When I step through Visual Studio, I noticed that there are multiple same entries in openList that is not being caught by the lambda expression. Could anyone enlighten me as to what I had done wrong since I am never entering the do-something loop at all? Thanks alot.

Comment: Are you comparing integers or floats?

Comment: What is the return type of `GetXPos() and GetZPos()`?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with that code. The problem probably lies in the comparison between whatever `GetXPos()` and `GetZPos()` return.

If they are integers, it should be fine and the code should work.

If they are doubles or floats, you must use some other way of comparing them [(see this StackOverflow question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison).

If they are objects implemented by you, double check how they are determined to be equal (your implementation of `operator==` for those objects).